# How do I turn this while loop into a for loop?

Tags: java, loops

Having trouble with for loops on java.
How do I turn this while loop into a for loop?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            int down;
            down = 5;
            while (down > 0) {
                    System.out.println(down);
                    down = down - 1;
```

I want to just countdown from 5 (5 4 3 2 1)

for (down = 5; down > 0 down-- );

This just outputs:

5

Comment: `for (int down = 5; down > 0; down--) System.out.println(down);`

Answer (score 1):

You are reducing `down` variable twice or more. You should remove `down = down -1` line if you want to use for loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int down;
    down = 5;
    for (down=5;down>0;down--) {
       System.out.println(down);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should revisit the Core Java concepts. That's not how we use for-loops. You need to specify the start of the loop, u need to specify the condition until when you want to stay inside the loop, and then iteration logic .. i.e forward or backward.

See below :

Code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int down = 0;
    for (down = 5; down > 0 ; down-- ){
        System.out.println(down);
    }
        
}
```

Output :

5
4
3
2
1